# How to pass a value to a subtitution variable using select script

Tags: sql, oracle, bind-variables, substitution-variables

I have a SQL script in which I declare some substitution variables at the top. The purpose of the script is to create a set of tables and views on a bunch of Oracle schemas when doing multi tenant deployment.
In one of the scripts that creates tables, a table space is assigned. Since the table space name varies from tenant to tenant, I want to extract the table space name from the schema and put it in as a substitution variable that I can then use through the script that creates tables and views.

An example:

```
define VISchema   = FCFVI0

 CREATE TABLE "&VISchema."."FSV_LIST_INFO" 
("LIST_KEY" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE, 
    "LIST_REFERENCE" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "LIST_SOURCE" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "LAST_SCREENED" DATE, 
    "LAST_UPDATE" DATE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "&tablespace_nm."   NO INMEMORY ;
```

I want to assign a value to the tablespace_nm substitution variable using the output from:

```
select tablespace_name from user_tablespaces;
```

But I have not figured out how.

If doing:

```
variable tablespace_nm_1 CHAR;
exec select tablespace_name into :tablespace_nm from user_tablespaces;
```

and I try to reference that variable as `:tablespace_nm` it says the tablespace does not exist.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it sql-server or oracle ? Those are 2 different databases, please tag the correct ones only.

Comment: The syntax _&<parameter>._ is wrong. You don't need the "." at the end. Also, you cannot bind table names, schema names afaik. You could do it in a pl/sql block using dynamic sql

Comment: @KoenLostrie [**substitution** variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-0BEEC1D7-876B-495C-9327-17037652D3D2) is an entity of SQL*Plus, it is not a **bind** variable. So syntax is correct

Comment: @astentx thanks for the correction, I was under the impression until now that it was used for bind variables only. But there is a typo in the syntax. As the doc states, **&VARIABLE** will work, however the OP is using the syntax **&VARIABLE.** - note the "." at the end.

Comment: @KoenLostrie In *6.3.1 Where and How to Use Substitution Variables* section: *If you wish to append characters immediately after a substitution variable, use a period to separate the variable from the character. For example: `SELECT SALARY FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='&X.5'`* Because it is **substitution** variable, it just replaces part of the text and is processed by SQL*Plus, when bind variable is the data and is processed at parsing time. So in bind case it will be equivalent to `<expression>.<expression>` which is not a valid syntax

Comment: @astentx I stand corrected - thanks :)

Comment: @KoenLostrie Welcome! It's essential to distinguish them both

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have that *script* which contains bunch of tables you're going to create, **maybe** the simplest option is to open it in any decent text editor and perform *search & replace*, providing new values.

---

Otherwise, in my database, your way wouldn't work because `user_tablespaces` doesn't contain just one tablespace (so your `select` would fail with too_many_rows):

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from user_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS
```

Do you *really* see just one tablespace?

Anyway, for this demonstration, I'll use a `where` clause to select only one tablespace: `users`.

In SQL*Plus, you can use substitution variables ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-396C98D4-3296-44E4-9CC9-CBC0B2DF9011) is here). Here's how:

```
SQL> column tablespace_name new_value ts
```

`tablespace_name` won't get its value until you select it:

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from user_tablespaces
  2  where tablespace_name = 'USERS';

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
USERS
```

OK; let's create table, providing tablespace name via substitution variable:

```
SQL> create table test (id number) tablespace &ts;
old   1: create table test (id number) tablespace &ts
new   1: create table test (id number) tablespace USERS

Table created.

SQL>
```

Looks like it *works*.